# Why can't I edit topic title in documentation

Tags: support, documentation-topics

Why can't I edit topic title in documentation?

I see that there's a [request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jmeter/1941/getting-started-with-jmeter#t=201707250722514360692) that Topic title should change but I can't edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Getting started with [tag]" topic is *special*. Its title cannot be changed, nor can this topic be deleted outright if it is inappropriate for a particular tag.

If you hover over the "Introduction Topic" badge, you'll see the following tooltip:

[image: "This topic is an introduction to jmeter and lists its versions. This topic cannot be deleted and its title cannot be changed.]

Although I have no idea why, this is obviously by design. I guess the thinking is that *every* tag we document needs a "getting started" page, and the team wanted them to be consistently labeled.

I don't know what jmeter is, but [we have this page for the [windows] tag documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/windows/1710/getting-started-with-windows#t=201707251147134265408), and it's utterly absurd. It's received 8 downvotes, 0 upvotes, and everyone wants to delete it, but we can't. It makes no sense to document how to get started with Windows, and although we *could* document all of the versions of Windows, that's just pointless busy work. Other sites already do a much better job of maintaining such a list.

---

But, looking at [the improvement request](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jmeter/1941/getting-started-with-jmeter#t=201707250722514360692), the suggestion is just to change the name from "jmeter" to "Apache JMeter", and that actually *can* be done. You just do it in a confusing, hard-to-find way. You actually want to go to [the wiki for the [jmeter] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jmeter/info), click the "Edit Tag Info" button at the very bottom, and fill in the "Friendly name for Documentation".

I've gone ahead and made this change. Should be live now.

Comment: The community want to change the title, should there be an bug/enhancement request?

Comment: @user7294900 Took a closer look and updated the answer. Should be done now.